# css selector for all input elements except a few

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I have a HTML form containing 10 input elements and I want to call a function on keypress on each of those input elements except 2 of those

```
$(":input").live("keypress", function(e){ 
// something...
});
```

The above selector will work for all input elements. But I want to exclude 2 of my input elements (By id or By class) from the above code. How shall I do it? Is there an **exclude/ not** feature in css selector?

The other way of doing it can be by appending the id's of the input elements to be included by something like "keypress_" and then using

```
$("[id^=keypress_]").live("keypress", function(e){ 
// something...
});
```

But I donot want to change the HTML ids. Can this be done by css selector?

Comment: Are you sure you want a pure CSS selector and not use any of the ones jQuery offers? Because `:input` is not a CSS selector.

Comment: Sorry.. I thought :input is a CSS selector. Anyways :input:not([id^=keypress_]) has done the trick for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use `:not` selector or the `.not` jQuery method.  Both should work the same in this case.

```
$(":input:not([id^=keypress_]")
$(":input").not("[id^=keypress_]")
```

---

Do not use `.live` as it has been removed in jQuery 1.9.  Use event delegation via `.on` instead:

```
$(document).on('keypress', ':input:not([id^=keypress_])', function () {
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a `:not()` selector in jQuery, and also a `.not()` method.

This may work for you:

```
$(":input:not([id^=keypress_])")
```

Or this:

```
$(":input").not("[id^=keypress_]")
```

This link may have more information.
http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/